# CrudRepository: findBy... but without returning the values of a column

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have a table with columns like this:

```
ID | A | B | C
```

I have a class with the attributes ID, A and B but without the attribute C.
I want to implement a CrudRepository find method (for example findAllByA) that takes every row that matches the query but without returning C so the result can be bound to my class.

I know I could have a secondary class with all four arguments and then convert the collection of results to a collection of results of the class I actually want, but I'd rather avoid this.

Comment: If you already have a class which holds only ID, A and B, then why not use it directly like `@Query("select new com.example.YourClass(e.ID, e.A, e.B) from YourEntity e where...")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply return an instance of your class from your method.

For example :

```java
public interface YourRepository extends CrudRepository<YourModel, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.example.YourClass(e.ID, e.A, e.B) FROM YourEntity e WHERE e.A = ?1")
    List<YourClass> findByA(String filter);

}
```

So the result is bound to your class directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think, mapping is the best choice in this situation. Because YourClass is DTO object and if you change your mind and change the internal structure YourClass in the project, you can only change the mapper code. **Yann39's** solution is acceptable but if you change the structure of **YourClass** class, you will need to change every **Query** related to it.